# Jssor Nested slider Bullet scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am using JSSOR slider plugin an have a problem with my nested fullscreen slider:

I have several nested sliders, each of them with a separate bulletnavigator. Even when I add `$Scale: false` to the `$BulletNavigatorOptions` for each slider, the bullets keeps scaling on window resize (I am guessing it is caused by the sliders beeing nested?!). On top of that, it seems like I can't set the navigator to be fixed, on window resize the BulletNavigator gets pushed outside of the viewport.

@jssor Do you have any suggestions, what I might be missing? Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that in case of nested slider, child sliders don't scale, the scaling applies to the main slider only. So, `$Scale: false` for navigator of child slider would not work.

Comment: Can you show your code sample?